# Setting the size of an array when using String Split Method

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

I am trying to declare an array of size 3, then use the string `split()` method to assign values to each index of the array. However, the `Split()` method seems to override the size of the array and sets its size to the amount of substrings the `Split()` method comes out with.

So This is what I did,

```
string myString = "Hello world";
string[] myArray = new string[3];

for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    myArray[i] = "";

myArray = myString.Split(' ');
```

But once again, when I use the `Split()` method, it overrides the size of my array and sets it to 2 which causes complications for me later on.

So I need to know how to use the split method to add strings into the array of size 3. If the array contains less than 3 items, I want to set the unassigned indexes to `""` and if there are more than 3 substrings then I want to only take the first three and discard the rest.

Thanks in advance for any help guys.

Comment: Why not fix it on the other end? Just check the length of it.

Comment: It may be worth creating an extension method for this. Check my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the result of the string split to a new array, transferring the contents to the original array in a loop. If the string split array is longer than the original array then the original should be set to the new one in order to avoid an out of bounds exception.

```
var splitArray = myString.Split(' ');
if(splitArray.Length >= myArray.Length)
{
    myArray = splitArray;
}
else
{
    for(int i = 0; i < splitArray.Length; i++)
        myArray[i] = splitArray[i];
}
```

Comment: Worked great. The only small change I had to make was add a for loop to the `if` body that loops from 0 -> `myArray.Length` so the `myArray` won't take more than 3 items when the `splitArray` is greater than 3. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Just needs a little re-jig (updated to cope with the case where the myArray is smaller than mySplitString):

```
string myString = "Hello world";
string[] mySplitString = myString.Split(' ');

string[] myArray = new string[3];
var loopLength = Math.min(mySplitString.length,myArray.length);

for(int i = 0; i < loopLength; i++){
    myArray[i] = mySplitString[i];
}
```

Comment: `Array.Copy` would be an option too.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another idea; I have used an extension method called ConsistantSplit here. So you can split the string in to a consistent size array.

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        string myString = "Hello world";
        var mySplitedString = myString.ConsistantSplit(' ', 5);
        Console.WriteLine(mySplitedString.Length);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static string[] ConsistantSplit(this string text, char splitter, int size)
    {
        string[] consistantSplitter = new string[size];
        var splitted = text.Split(splitter);
        if (size < splitted.Length)
            return splitted.Take(size).ToArray();
        splitted.CopyTo(consistantSplitter, 0);
            return consistantSplitter;
    }
```